# setting up multiple ssl certificates on same server/ip on CENTOs with apache 2.2

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm [using this reference](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm) to setup multiple ssl ceritificates on same ip on CENTOS 6.3 with apache 2.2

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.domain1.org
        ServerAlias domain1.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain1.org/

        #   SSL Engine Switch:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.                                                                                                                                                                            
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing                                                                                                                                                    
        #   the ssl-cert package. See                                                                                                                                                                                            
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.                                                                                                                                                      
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the                                                                                                                                                    
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.                                                                                                                                                                              
        SSLCertificateFile  /home/tmp/ssl/domain1.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/tmp/ssl/domain1.key

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.domain2.org
        ServerAlias domain2.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain2.org/

        #   SSL Engine Switch:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.                                                                                                                                                                            
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing                                                                                                                                                    
        #   the ssl-cert package. See                                                                                                                                                                                            
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.                                                                                                                                                      
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the                                                                                                                                                    
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.                                                                                                                                                                              
        SSLCertificateFile  /home/tmp/ssl/domain2.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/tmp/ssl/domain2.key

</VirtualHost>
```

upon start I receive the following warning:

```
[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 443, the first has precedence
```

when I visit the different sites, it still always shows me the first cerficicate. what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable SNI ability. Enable with in ports.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
```